# EF, Add-Migration; Cannot execute this command because the version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design installed is not compatible with this tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

Recently, when executing Add-Migration command I'm receiving the fallowing error

```
Cannot execute this command because the version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design installed is not compatible with this tool.
```

My current project.json

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "System.Linq.Queryable": "4.0.1",
    "System.Linq.Dynamic.Core": "1.0.6.8",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

but I tried as well with version

```
 "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1"
```

Both dotnet restore and dotnet -ef commands are executing without any problems.

Thanks,
Konrad

Comment: `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final"` << you add `preview2-final` in the dependencies, but preview3-final in the tools

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the error now changed to No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Comment: You sure the dependency is there? There is no entry in dependencies section, so unless you had older framework installed before it won't be there in the cache. Try add it to the dependencies section too (the tools entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tseng,
It started working after changing to:

```
  "tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

},